# Depth first search current implementation problem when I try to run it

Tags: python-3.x, search, graph, microsoft-distributed-file-system, undirected-graph

I'm here trying to share my depth first-search (DFS) implementation. I'm trying to learn how can it traverse in a graph that is undirected, meaning that not all nodes are making into one graph, but two different ones. I was looking for the small basics of DFS with one graph only. And I came across to a problem in *"what would happen if there are more than one graph and are not connected?"* So I started to look around how to do it by using my knowledge from the simple DFS implementation. However, it is a little bit more complicated than I thought. Here is the code sample that I came across:

```
"""DFS implemention."""

    adjacency_matrix = {
                        1: [2, 3],
                        2: [4, 5],
                        3: [5],
                        4: [6],
                        5: [6],
                        6: [7],
                        7: [],
                        8: [9],
                        9: [8]
                        }

        def DFS_un(graph):
        """Traversal for undirected graphs."""
            vertices = graph[0]
            edges = graph[1]

        def visit(vertex):
            if vertex in visited:
                return
            visited.add(vertex)
            print(vertex)
            if vertex in edges:
                for e in edges[vertex]:
                    visit(e)
        visited = {}
        for v in vertices:
            visit(v)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        DFS_un(adjacency_matrix)
```

And the error message says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dfs.py", line 33, in <module>
    DFS_dis(adjacency_matrix)
  File "dfs.py", line 17, in DFS_dis
    vertices = graph[0]
KeyError: 0
```

If you see, I'm using one graph, but it has undirected numbers, which is 8 and 9 (8<->9). Why am I not getting my output correctly? Sorry, learning some Python3 too :). Thanks for your help!

Comment: `vertices = graph[0]` is an indentation error, and also refers to the missing key.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
vertices = graph.keys()
edges = graph.values()
```

'Graph' is a dictionary object.  The graph[0] notation says find me the value associated with the key=0.  Since you have no key=0 you get an error.

You might be confusing dictionaries with lists.  my_list[0] says get me the value at position 0 in my_list.

Comment: I want to keep the visited vertices into `visited` as a dictionary, so that way I can pull which ones I have visited without computing it again.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, I saw what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem already. @blueenvelope was right with the idea of the dictionary because there are no KeyWords used and thus giving me 0 for some reason... At the end, it finally reads the whole graph list from unconnected vertices.

My variables `vertices` and `edges` were incorrectly implemented and quickly understood it's purpose. **Keys** is used to find particular dictionaries, so I was pulling keys from the graph vertex. Same goes for my edges, but also pulling the **values** of those edges from a specific key. Here is the full fixed code:

```
adjacency_matrix = {
                    1: [2, 3],
                    2: [4, 5],
                    3: [5],
                    4: [6],
                    5: [6],
                    6: [7],
                    7: [],
                    8: [9],
                    9: [8]
                    }

def DFS_un(graph):
    """Traversal for undirected graphs."""
    vertices = graph.keys()
    edges = graph.values()
    visited = []

    def visit(vertex):
        if vertex in visited:
            return
        print("Visited vertex: ")
        visited.append(vertex)
        print(visited)
        print("Current vertex: ")
        print(vertex)
        print("\n")
        if vertex in edges:
            for e in edges[vertex]:
                visit(e)
    for v in vertices:
        visit(v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DFS_un(adjacency_matrix)
```